# Selecting an option on a dynamically-populated select element in jQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a dynamically-populated select box which is intended to be used for displaying information about a single option. The problem I've got is that it doesn't seem to fire a `:selected` event in the browser when I click on any of the options.

I won't know in the future what the information is, but shouldn't a `.val()` (in theory) get the value of the options which have been dynamically populated? So far it doesn't seem to be working.

The **original HTML**:

```
<select id="activeList" size="5">
</select>
```

The options are populated with the following **javascript** (and it works great, the JSON data seems to be a breeze to work with and I'm happy to start using it):

```
function popuList(){
    // Populates the SELECT element with options from the JSON file.
    var url = "/calls/sessions.php";
    var list = '';
    $.getJSON(url,'',function(jdata,oSucc,jqXHR){
        $.each(jdata,function(i,session){
            $.each(session,function(n,data){
                list += "\n" + '<option value="'+data.name+'">'+data.name+'</option>';
            });
        });
        $("#activeList").html(list);
    });
}
```

The problem is that I can't seem to grab the value of the selected option so that I can dynamically update other elements on the page. I've tried `.val()` and `:selected` and even putting the list items into a global array variable... nothing seems to be working, and I'm not really sure why.

When I inspect the elements in the browser (FF and Chrome), the options are there, but none of them have a selected attribute when I click them. The code seems not to care whether any of them are selected or not. That being the case, how would I detect interaction with the list?

In the inspector the HTML looks something like:

```
<select id="activeList" size="5">
  <option value="00000000003">00000000003</option>
  <option value="00000000002">00000000002</option>
  <option value="00000000001">00000000001</option>
</select>
```

For future reference (and as a reminder) I'm not going to necessarily know the values. Is what I want to do even possible?

The above function is called once each pageload from the `$(document).ready(function(){}` callback. If it matters, jQuery 1.11.1 is the version in use. The browsers are all fully up to date. I'm using Notepad++ for editing. Not sure what other info would be helpful.

Comment: what is the need of '\n' there?

Comment: Its only use is to prettify the code so that I know what I'm looking at when I go through the code. It adds a newline. I get lost less that way.

Comment: where have you used `.val()` or `:selected`? could you please share that code also.

Comment: you have different `id`s on your select elements given in example

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo... fixed.

Comment: Because list is created dynamically, and it is not present on DOM ready, i have feel that using of on() method and delegated events could be solution: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: I was going to add some examples of nonworking code, but then I thought: "why would people need nonworking code if there's a solution otherwise?" So... no, not posting a bunch of nonworking, already-deleted, rack-my-brain-to-recreate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the HTML of a select element dynamically is bound to cause problems. It is best to use JavaScript itself in order to let the browser properly handle it. [Click here to see how](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp)

Comment: This is actually the direction I should have probably chosen, though when I actually tried it there still wasn't the ability to detect when an object was selected... e.g., no ":selected" attribute that javascript would recognize as selected.

Comment: The selected attribute is only meant to be used to determine the default elected option. Use the select element's value attribute instead.

Comment: I don't yet have enough rep to upvote this, but it is actually what led me to the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onclick event and then get the selected value by using the following

```
<select id="activeList" size="5" onclick='onclicklist()'>
</select>

<script>
    function onclicklist() {
        var selectedvalue = $("#activelist option:selected").val();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that in the dynamically generated code, it's not really :selected at any point... that's the entire problem. So while your solution might work on pre-populated lists, it doesn't actually work in the code right now. And yes, I just tried it.

Comment: So what does it give you, is it null, the first item, or what?

Comment: It gives me an `undefined` as if I have nothing there to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

First, some browsers don't respond well to having a select node populated with `.html(...)`. It's far safer to append option nodes.

Second, to respond to user selections of the populated select element, you need to attach an 'onchange' handler. The attachment can be made before or after the options have been added.

```
function popuList() {
    var $select = $("#activeList").on('change', function() {
        var val = this.value;
        //do real kewl stuff with the value here
    });
    // Populates the SELECT element with options from the JSON file.
    var url = "/calls/sessions.php";
    $.getJSON(url, '', function(jdata, oSucc, jqXHR){
        $.each(jdata,function(i, session) {
            $.each(session, function(n, data) {
                $('<option value="' + data.name + '">' + data.name + '</option>').appendTo($select);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but would the selected element be accessible outside of the function to other functions, or would I need to drop information back into a database handler (for example a getJSON() or get()) for that other stuff to be accessible again?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean but will try to answer. Anything declared with `var` inside a function is local to that function (and any inner functions). In the case of `$select`, `var $select = $("#activeList")` anywhere else in your code will refer to the same element, and `$select.val()` will return the value of the currently selected option. If, in some other code, you needed to know all the session values, you could theoretically read them from the options in `#activeList`, however you would need to know what you're doing as the other code may run before the select box is populated.

Comment: That's a much more specific answer than my vague question, lol.

Comment: It was difficult to not pick this, as it seemed at first to be a great answer, but ultimately the problem I was having required knowledge I didn't yet have about the order of operations... I'm still overcoming procedural thinking vs. OO thinking. So while this would technically resolve the immediate issue (and I did in fact credit you in the comments of my code as "Roamer-1888 at Stack Overflow" because my final answer was in fact very similar), the ultimate issue was the way I was thinking about the problem.

Comment: It was in fact a tough call.