# PHP not loading inline

Tags: php

I have a php file with the following code which is run inside a switch statement:

```
switch($valueFoo) {
case 'bar':
echo "<select id=\"selTheme\">";

        $path = './files/css/themes/';
        $files = array_values(array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..')));
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
            $cVal = substr($files[$i], 0, -4);
            $cTitle  = ucwords(substr($files[$i], 0, -4));
            if ($cTitle==$_SESSION['setTheme']) {
                echo "<option value='" . $cVal . "' onclick=\"changeColors('" . $cVal . "')\" selected>" . $cTitle . "</option>";
            } elseif ($i>=count($files)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $cVal . "' onclick=\"changeColors('" . $cVal . "')\">" . $cTitle . "</option></select>";
            } else {
                echo "<option value='" . $cVal . "' onclick=\"changeColors('" . $cVal . "')\">" . $cTitle . "</option>";
            }
        }

echo "...";
```

This is intended to create a list of options from a folder on my server.  And it does indeed work.  The problem is that it ONLY works AFTER the page is refreshed.  I have been banging my head on my table trying to figure out why it does this only after the page is refreshed.  I have no clue.  I want the element to be filled with options as soon as it loads on page.  I don't want the page to reload at all.  It works by itself to populate an unordered list but I want it to be selectable options.

I don't see anything wrong with the code at all.  I don't understand why the options list aren't being populated without a reloading of the page.  I don't understand why it fills in perfectly when the page reloads.  I would think that if it would do it properly AFTER the reload, it would do it just fine the first time it loads!  Why isn't?

Please help me understand.

**EDIT:** This code comes as a return from an AJAX call.  I am trying to run the for loop from that AJAX call.  The loop doesn't run until the page reloads.  Is there a way to force the AJAX call without the page load?

Comment: There are lots of possibilities.  Your snippet is incomplete.  Do you have an `exit` at the end of your case statement?  How do we know that 'bar' is even being executed?  This doesn't actually look like the real code ($valueFoo?)  You are asking people to guess.

Comment: The `</select>` closing tag should be echoed on its own before the last `echo '...';`

Comment: Aside: Your second conditional will never be satisfied.  You'll never close the select.

Comment: What does $valueFoo rely upon?

Comment: Yes.  The code is not complete.  I posted the relavent portion.  As I stated before, everything else around this code loads properly.  This section, and only this section, does not.  The case IS being selected an ran.  The page reflects that.  Both before and after this code.  This part of the code is not ran or displayed unless the page is refreshed.  Then it runs flawlessly.  I need to know why.   And yes, foo and bar has long since been used as nonsensical variable placeholders in psudeocode.

Comment: @omar tanti and progrock specifically:  this code is a product of my trying to fix the issue.  Initially, the closing of the select was by itself.  I purposefully moved it to its current location.  However, the second condition is indeed reached and the select is properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a dynamic display of the folders content you'll have to use Ajax.
make sure that the session is already created and you're using *'session_start()'* in the beginning of all your pages,
clarify your question/code to get precise answers

Comment: No.  I’m sorry.  You’re completely wrong.  AJAX is absolutely 100% not required to load the contents of a folder on the server.  Thanks for the attempt, though.

Comment: You might actually be on to something here but in reverse.  I'm trying to run a for loop that is a RETURN from an AJAX call.  Apparently, that doesn't happen?  Any idea how to do that?

Comment: if you need to repopulate only the '<select>' '<options>' when you click a button or with some timer, you need to do this with ajax/jQuery, this post may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582354/selecting-an-option-on-a-dynamically-populated-select-element-in-jquery-ajax